# I'm making a model of a milk carton, but when I inset a triangle face, it overlaps

Tags: modeling

I used a block and I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> on the sides to make a triangle and when I inset a face on the side of the triangle it overlaps, but that never happened before.

[image]

Comment: Are some normal directions reversed?

Answer (score 1):

You probably forgot to turn on Auto Merge vertices! Because of that there are 2 vertices in the same position instead of one and blender doesn't know how to make an inset. (or rather it does, but the topology becomes messed up which you do not want)

[image]
Left geometry doesn't have merged vertices, right one does

To make sure this doesn't happen in the future you can turn on auto merge vertices in the upper toolbar. Whenever two vertices share the same position they are merged together. This will however work only if you create the geometry after turning auto merge on. It will not merge already existing vertices
[image]

You can merge the vertices of already existing geometry manually either by selecting them by hand and merging (M -> at center, collapse, at cursor) or using the merge by distance command. (M -> merge by distance) which merges every vertice that is closer than certain treshold

Comment: THANKYOU SO MUCHHHH